# How to select one group with group by?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

We have an Oracle 11g table with about 75M rows. One column is called called DOKUMENTUMID with more or less unique values, except a few thousand duplicate rows. Due to legacy software, we were not able to add a unique constraint on this field.

However, now we are able to add a unique index, but to achieve that first we have to clean up the current duplicates. To do that we have to execute other complex operations not available from SQL. (File system changes/calling an API method, etc...)

We have a standard Java architecture that works well for this kind of tasks. This Java EE application has a singleton class that is called by a scheduler. This singleton fetches the next task from the database and puts it in a JMS queue. A number of message driven beans are listening to these messages and are executing the task.

I am looking for a quick way to select a duplicate from the table and put it in the JMS queue. Currently my SQL sentence is the following.

```
select
inner_select.DOKUMENTUMID from (
    select
        inner_d.DOKUMENTUMID,
        count(*) CNT
    from 
        DOKUMENTUM inner_d
    group by 
        inner_d.DOKUMENTUMID
    having
        count(*) > 1
    ) inner_select
where
    rownum = 1
order by 
    inner_select.DOKUMENTUMID desc,
    inner_select.CNT desc;
```

It runs in about 20 seconds, which is a bit too slow. I think Oracle runs a full table scan on the 70M+ documents which is unnecessary, since we only need one group this time.

The plan explained:
[image: Explain plan]

Plan B is to run the scheduled method less frequently and add multiple messages to the queue at once, but I fear that might result in uneven system load.

Comment: You have an **index** on DOKUMENTUMID and tried the simple SELECT DOKUMENTUMID FROM ~ GROUP BY ~ HAVING ~ ORDER BY DOKUMENTUMID ?

Comment: The rownum stopkey limit is applied to the aggregation--it does a decent amount of scanning to get only the one row each time.  I wondered if you have freedom to create a short-lived work-table (or temp table, etc if the session is long-lived) and loading with the result of `inner_select` (only running the costly select once), then querying (and cleaning up) the work-table to queue the async processing rather than the inline view?  Are you free to cache or materialize the result of the inner_select?

Comment: Dear alexgibbs, Joop Eggen - Thank you for the replies! Yes, DOKUMENTUMID is indexed. And yes, I can create a working table which I am going to do to speed things up. Thank you very much!